# функция принимает массив и возвращает его сумму

Tags: javascript, массивы

Всем добрый день
Получил задание уже как дней 5, и вроде бы оно прям простое, но что бы я не попробовал, выдает или `ReferenceError` или `TypeError`
Суть задания – функция принимает массив чисел и возвращает его сумму

Пробовал через Sum+= и через reduce, но все тщетно.
Обыскал все, пробовал разные вариации написания – все бесполезно.
Надеюсь на понимание и помощь в разборе данного вопроса, спасибо

Comment: Покажите как пробовали

Comment: А код Ваш можно посмотреть? Странно как Вы получаете ошибки referenceerror или typeerror

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a.reduce((r, i) => r + i, 0));
```